# income taxes in France: Is it better to share our income taxes or pay separately, me and my gf?

Tags: income-tax, france

My lady and I are living in France and paying our taxes there, separately. However, we are considering to pay our taxes together for the first time.

Online simulator like the one below are not clear on how much we are going to gain

http://impotsurlerevenu.org/simulateurs/1100-simulateur-impot-2016.php

Questions are the following:

- How much are we going to gain if we are paying together?
- Is there something akin to a tax scale on when is more beneficial to pay together and when it is better to pay taxes each on our own?

Any tips are more than welcomed as the legality is far from clear.

Thanks

Comment: Can unmarried people file together?

Comment: Hi @JoeTaxpayer, yes you can. Under the civil solidarity pact also known as [Pacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_solidarity_pact), you have a limited form of marriage, which include taxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you'll pay less taxes if you do a common declaration.

## Why?!

Because the Quotient Familial (QF) helps you. This is simple mathematics : If salary 1 = salary 2, you gain/lose nothing. If salary 1 and salary 2 are quite different (for example if one doesn't work, or one is part-time while the other is full-time...), you'll save quite a lot. 
Let's say you are taxed on 30 000€, and your significant other is taxed on 20 000€.

### Two declarations scenario

#### You

You are alone (QF = 1), and declare 30 000€, which will go into these slices. 
0% of 9710€ = 0€ 
14% of 17107€ = 2394,98€ 
30% of 3181€ = 954,3€ 
Total : 3349,28€

#### Your SO

Your SO is alone (QF = 1), and declares 20 000€, which will go into these slices. 
0% of 9710€ = 0€ 
14% of 10290€ = 1440,60€ 
Total : 1440,60€

Grand Total : 4789,88€

### Common declaration scenario

You are considered a couple (QF = 2), and combine your declarations : 50 000€.

Since QF = 2, you calculate as if you were declaring 50 000 / 2 = 25 000€, which will go into these slices. 
0% of 9710€ = 0€ 
14% of 15290€ = 2140,60€ 
Total : 2140,60€

This gives you the tax for a part. Multiply it with QF. 
Grand Total : 2140,60 x 2 = 4281,20€.

### Result

In this example, doing a common declaration will allow you to save 4789,88 - 4281,20 = 508,68€.